# Class 'Url' not found in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm creating a login and logout page on a custom template in yii2. I got an error because of routing.

Please tell how to import Url or manage url.

[image: Class Url not found]

Comment: if there is code, add it as text/code block to your question. do not add a screenshot of your code! if you want help from coders, give them code. that is their language.

Answer (score 16):

Add `Url` class in top of the page.

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
```

Refer [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail)